# Show ALL Permission Groups in Admin Center?

Tags: sharepoint-online, groups, sharepoint-permissions

I'm quite new to using the Admin Center for my SharePoint Management needs, and I am wondering :

**Is it possible to see ALL Permission Groups that have been created on my SharePoint?**

We only recently started using **SharePoint Online** so there are not many Sites/Users actually using it yet.

Any assistance is appreciated!   Cheers!

1 Year Later Update -

I'm with a different company now, and am running into the same issue.  Is there a way to do this without using PowerShell?  This was very easily achieved in past versions of SharePoint, but I'm starting to believe it's not that easy now.  I would just like to see all SharePoint User/Permission Groups.  Any assistance with this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can get users and groups of all SharePoint Online site collections using PowerShell.

For more detailed information, refer to the following articles:

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/06/sharepoint-online-site-users-and-groups-report-powershell.html

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/powershell/manage-sharepoint-users-and-groups-with-powershell

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/powershell/manage-sharepoint-site-groups-with-powershell

Comment: Lisa, I just found out how to open PowerShell.  I'm terribly inexperienced with "code" and am trying not to break anything haha Is it as easy as copy/pasting those code blocks into the Prompt to get results?